# Keyboard enter button on input

Tags: javascript, input, enter

Anyone can teach me how to make input button onlick when press the keyboard "Enter" ?

What i have study from web is something like this , but it's does't work when i press enter from keyboard . Anyone can show me how ??

```
<input type="text" id="info" name="info" />
<input type="button" id="bn" name="bn" value="click" onclick="read()" />

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#info').keypress(function(e){
      if(e.keyCode==13)
      $('#bn').click();
    });
});

function read()
{
// do smth
}
</script>
```

Comment: Your code should work.

Comment: your code is fine. see it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/1wt90mty/

Comment: but when i click enter it nothing happen ...

Comment: @JackLee what browser are you using?

Comment: have you added jQuery library before using your script?

Comment: opps yes i forgot to add jQuery library = =... too careless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am adding fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/nzu27rw4/1/
**make sure that you have added jquery reference on the top of this script**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#info').keypress(function(e){
      if(e.keyCode==13)
      $('#bn').click();
    });
});

function read()
{
alert('read')
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="info" name="info" />
<input type="button" id="bn" name="bn" value="click" onclick="read()" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
    <input type="text" id="info" name="info" />
    <input type="button" id="bn" name="bn" value="click" onclick="read()" />

    <script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#info').keyup(function(e){
      if(e.keyCode==13)
      $('#bn').trigger("click");
    });
});

function read()
{
alert('clicked')
}
    </script>
```